# Issue in calling DAO method from Service

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, dao

I have a DAO that has method like this:

```
class AbcService 
{
  private AbcDAO isntance;
  public void getStuff()
  {
    instance.getQueryResult();
  }
}
```

Now if this method is called from anywhere it will give a NullPointerException where instance calls the query method.
    Still this code is in use in the project from a long time and i would think twice before calling it incorrect. Is there some way by which this code can be accessed. Is this a standard practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a setter for `isntance`, you just need to call it before calling `getStuff`. This is standard (although some would say all needed fields should be set inside a constructor.

Comment: for that i have a method: 
public void setAbcDAO(final AbcDAO isntance) { 
this.isntance = instance; 
} 

But i dont know where and how is this being called...

Comment: So it is standard. You just need to call the setter before calling `getStuff`

Comment: just one issue...instance is declared as private..how can i call it from any other class

Answer (score 1):

This answer just applies if you are using springbean and its broader than your question.. But I guess this will be useful to you

Yes this is generally used practice when you are using it as a spring bean. So, before calling this method, you need to be sure that this springbean is instantiated. Basically, this is done by either getting spring bean from ApplicationContext or the caller class itself receives instance of this bean from its parent bean....

General practise is to load application context by defining contextloaderlistener in web.xml. For more info on how to do it, see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the object `instance` is **injected** to `AbcService` via the [Spring Dependency Injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/beans.html). Please search for any ".xml" file in your project, which has fully qualified class name of AbcService mentioned in its bean definition.